# opening tap target in materialize css for 2 seconds

Tags: materialize

I need to open Tap target in materialize css for 2 seconds & close it. All I can see is ('.tap-target').tapTarget('open'); & $('.tap-target').tapTarget('close');

Is there a way to open it for a specific time(say 2 seconds) & close it.

Also , is there a way to set its size on the screen ?

TIA
Jagan

Answer (score 0):

You can use setTimeout to "schedule" the execution of a piece of code in the future, e.g. in 2 seconds from now:

```
$('.tap-target').tapTarget('open');
setTimeout(function(){ $('.tap-target').tapTarget('close'); }, 2000);
```

It will wait the given number of milliseconds (here 2000) and then execute the given function. Give this a try, it should be fairly straightforward.

I don't understand your 2nd question about the size though.

Comment: Thank you @hendrikbeck, this really helps.